# How to make a 2 second popup in Windows (.exe file)

Tags: windows, popup, splash-screen

Just wondering: what program is used to create a .exe file where the purpose of the .exe file is only to popup, display a frameless/borderless image and then disappear after 1 or 2 seconds. Like when opening the program Microsoft Excel, upon opening you are presented the splash screen (call it like that?).

I would like to open the .exe file from a cad-software (startapp "mySplash.exe"). My question is not to provide me code or out of the box solutions but to learn what software is used for creating such .exe file.

Thanks and have a nice day!

Googled a lot but can't seem to find what I am looking for, I suspect I am using the wrong words to search for but I don't know what words to search for.